# How to use WP_Query to filter posts modified after a specific date

Tags: wp-query

I'm looking for a way to get all posts modified after a specific date, but still couldn't find an answer for that online; All websites says that this is still not supported until now.

Is querying posts modified after a date supported in Wordpress now? If it's supported, how can I achieve that?

If it's not supported yet, is there an alternative way I can achieve the same thing by modifying the global `$wp_query` object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible, using the [`date_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) argument. By default this uses the publication date, but you can tell it to use the modified date by using the `column` argument. So if you wanted to query all posts *modified* after June 30th 2019, you'd use:

```
'date_query' => [
    'column' => 'post_modified',
    'after'  => [
        'year'  => 2019,
        'month' => 6,
        'day'   => 30,
    ],
],
```

The `column` parameter of `WP_Date_Query` supports:

- `post_date` (default)
- `post_date_gmt`
- `post_modified`
- `post_modified_gmt`
- `comment_date`
- `comment_date_gmt`

A WP shell example for the date query in `WP_Query` with `post_modified_gmt` and the `after` parameter:

```
wp> echo ( new WP_Query( [ 'date_query' => [ [ 'column' => 'post_modified_gmt', 
  'after' => '2 days ago' ] ] ] ) )->request;
```

will output:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM tfl_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (
  wp_posts.post_modified_gmt > '2019-11-16 10:00:27'
```

For further information look e.g. into the dev documents here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_date_query/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

Comment: Just appended my working answer draft to your answer  ;-)